# Create stacked bar sparkline within renderDatatable in R shiny

Tags: shiny, stacked-chart, sparklines

I'm trying to replicate this [site_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2O9m.png) table in R shiny , using stacked bar chart within a column in a table. Here is the code that I'm using currently:

```
cost_data<- data.frame(site = c('Site 1', 'Site 2','Site 3', 'Site 4'),
                     cost = c("6,3,6,7", "7,4,7,5","3,2,2,2","6,5,3,2"))

ui <- fluidPage(sparklineOutput("details.1"),
DT::dataTableOutput("cost_table"))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$cost_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

dt <-  DT::datatable(as.data.frame(cost_data), rownames = FALSE,
options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1, render = 
 JS("function(data, type, full){ return '<span class=sparkSamples>' + data + '</span>' }"))),

fnDrawCallback = JS(paste0("function (oSettings, json) {\n  
$('.sparkSamples:not(:has(canvas))').sparkline('html', { ", "type: 'bar',
fillColor: 'black'", " });\n}"), collapse = "")))
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above code gives a simple bar chart. Can a horizontal stacked bar be added instead (as shown in image attached).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sparkline may not be able to do what you are looking for i.e., the stacked horizontal bar charts. But you can essentially render a custom JS code within the **columnDefs** of your **renderDataTable**.

Below is the sample code for the same-

```
# Prepare the Sample data
test_data <-
  data.table(
    Sites = c('Site1', 'Site2', 'Site3', 'Site4'),
    A = c(6, 3, 6, 7),
    B = c(7, 4, 7, 5),
    C = c(3, 2, 2, 2),
    D = c(6, 5, 3, 2)
  )

test_data$chart <- NA

# Define the Shiny UI and Custom CSS Elements
ui <- fluidPage(tags$head(tags$style(
  HTML(
    "
      .bar-chart-bar {
          background-color: #e8e8e8;
          display: block;
          position:relative;
          width: 100%;
          height: 20px;
      }
      .bar {
          float: left;
          height: 100%;
      }
      .bar1 {
          background-color: green;
      }
      .bar2 {
          background-color: yellow;
      }
      .bar3 {
          background-color: black;
      }
      .bar4 {
          background-color: blue;
      }
    "
  )
)), DT::dataTableOutput("test_table"))

# Rendering the DataTable in Shiny Server

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dt <-  DT::datatable(
      as.data.frame(test_data),
      rownames = FALSE,
      class = "compact display",
      options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
        targets = -1,
        render =
          JS(
            "function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return $('<div></div>', {
                            'class': 'bar-chart-bar'
                        }).append(function(){
                        console.log(row)
                        console.log(row[1])
                            var bars = [];
                            for(var i = 1; i < row.length; i++){
                                bars.push($('<div></div>',{
                                    'class': 'bar ' + 'bar' + i
                                }).css({
                                    'width': row[i] + '%'
                                }))
                            }
                            return bars;
                        }).prop('outerHTML')
                    }"
          )
      )))
    )
  })
}

# Run the App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Check below image for the output of above code to show Bar Chart within RenderDataTable -

[See Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwAT2.png)